# Classification compact oriented $2$-manifolds with boundary which admit a flat Riemannan structure

Tags: riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, surfaces, manifolds-with-boundary, flatness

The only compact orientable $n$-manifolds without boundary which can be given a flat Riemannan structure are tori. I was wondering if we could classify the compact oriented $2$-manifolds with boundary which admit flat Riemannan structures.

Are there any other than the torus and cylinder with disks cut out?

EDIT in response the comments: And disks of course

Comment: I think you can take the interior of any simple closed (smooth?) curve in the plane?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Every orientable surface with boundary. It is likely, the orientation assumption is not needed.

Comment: There are examples besides subsets of the plane, cylinder, and torus, including (suitable subsets of) cones with the vertex removed, and (suitable subsets of) polyhedra with the vertices removed (and the edges rounded off). These examples typically have non-trivial holonomy, while the plane, cylinder, and torus admit global parallel orthonormal frames (hence trivial holonomy around arbitrary curves).

Comment: @MoisheKohan how would you prove that?

Comment: Every orientable surface with nonempty boundary admits an immersion in Euclidean plane. It is a nice exercise to prove (using classification of surfaces), but also follows from Hirsch-Smale theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every compact surface with (nonempty) boundary admits a flat metric.  To get a classification, you need to also impose a condition on the mean curvature of the boundary.  I learned all of this from Osgood, Phillips, Sarnak, “[Extremals of determinants of Laplacians](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-1236(88)90070-5)”.

Here is a construction of a flat metric.
Fix a metric $g$ on the compact surface $\Sigma$ with (nonempty) boundary $\partial\Sigma$.
From the conformal transformation formula for the Gauss curvature, the metric $e^{2u}g$ will be flat with $e^{2u}g\rvert_{\partial\Sigma} = g\rvert_{\partial\Sigma}$ if and only if

$$ \label{eqn} \tag{$\ast$} \begin{cases} -\Delta u + K = 0 & \text{in $\Sigma$}, \\ u\rvert_{\partial\Sigma} = 0 . \end{cases} $$

Here $\Delta$ is the Laplacian with respect to $g$ and $K$ is the Gauss curvature of $g$.
The condition on the boundary is only there to make \eqref{eqn} well-defined.

One easy way to construct a solution of \eqref{eqn} is variationally.
Define $\mathcal{F} \colon C^\infty(\Sigma) \to \mathbb{R}$ by

$$ \mathcal{F}(u) := \int_\Sigma \left( \lvert\nabla u\rvert^2 + 2Ku \right) \, \mathrm{dvol}_g . $$

Any minimizer of

$$ \inf \left\{ \mathcal{F}(u) \mathrel{}:\mathrel{} u \in C^\infty(\Sigma) , u\rvert_{\partial\Sigma} = 0 \right\} $$

is necessarily a solution of \eqref{eqn}.
The infimum is finite by a combination of Hölder’s inequality and the Poincaré inequality.
Thus there is a minimizing sequence which converges to a minimizer of $\mathcal{F}$ in $W_0^{1,2}(\Sigma)$.
Since \eqref{eqn} is elliptic, a standard PDE argument implies that the minimizer is in fact smooth.